# I'm getting error Ultimate WooCommerce Filters

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

I Get an error when I want to add color or size in this plugin

## Error Details

An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 18 of the file /home/scrubers/public_html/wp-content/plugins/color-filters/Functions/Update_Admin_Databases.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /home/scrubers/public_html/wp-content/plugins/color-filters/Functions/Update_Admin_Databases.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 /home/scrubers/public_html/wp-content/plugins/color-filters/Functions/Update_Content.php(9): EWD_UWCF_Add_Color()
#1 /home/scrubers/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): EWD_UWCF_Update_Content('')
#2 /home/scrubers/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#3 /home/scrubers/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#4 /home/scrubers/public_html/wp-settings.php(546): do_action('init')
#5 /home/scrubers/public_html/wp-config.php(78): require_once('/home/scrubers/...')
#6 /home/scrubers/public_html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/scrubers/...')
#7 /home/scrubers/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/scrubers/...')
#8 {main}
thrown

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the relevant code](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/color-filters/tags/2.1.14/Functions/Update_Admin_Databases.php#L13) (lines 13, 17 and 18):

```php
$term = wp_insert_term(sanitize_text_field(
    $_POST['Color_Name']), 'product_color', $args);
$wc_term = wp_insert_term(sanitize_text_field(
    $_POST['Color_Name']), 'pa_ewd_uwcf_colors', $args);
update_term_meta($term['term_id'], 'EWD_UWCF_WC_Term_ID', $wc_term['term_id']);
```

You can see from the stack trace that either `$term` or `$wc_term` here must be a WP_Error object meaning that one of the wp_insert_term() calls failed. It would be useful to find out what that error is: I'd suggest adding

```
error_log( print_r( $term, true ) );
error_log( print_r( $wc_term, true ) );
```

between those two lines and reproducing the error again, then check your server or PHP error log to see the error details. After that I suggest you talk to the plugin authors and ask them to check `is_wp_error($term)` and `is_wp_error($wc_term)` here, and give them the error details too.